# query to get a distinct row in one to many mysql table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
  this is the company table
```

[image: this is the company table]

[image: this is the category table]

```
    this is the category table
```

how do i write a query such that it will select one distinct category and list all the companies that belongs to it.
e.g
school i.e category_id= 1 has two companies that belongs to it such as (Dolly, Abbey scaffold, AP).
Art i.e category_id=2 has one company (Blue script);
   this is the query that i have

```
            $query="SELECT distinct  company.id, company.company_name, category.category_name FROM company INNER JOIN category ON company.category_id =category.id ";
```

the query works fine but it keeps repeating the category_name that has many companies belonging to it. i want it to show category_name once and display the company that belongs to it under

Comment: "display the company that belongs to it under" what is that mean "under" ?

Comment: Are you using md5 or sha1 for password hashing? You should use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. Even if two users have the same password, the hash should be different or your users passwords can easily be broken by using rainbow tables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think I'm missing something. I don't even see the OP fetching or using passwords in any way?

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Look at the first screen shot of the db. Multiple users share the same password hashes :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Oh that's it. I can't see the screenshots (including my own profile picture!) because `imgur.com` is blocked on the network I am currently using. :(

Comment: the under dosent mean anything literally @Rainman. i just need the query to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*, t2.company_name

(Select id, category_name
from category) t1

left join

(select category_id, company_name
from company) t2

on t1.id=t2.category_id
```

Comment: describe your problem verbosely

Comment: @habibun i just need the query to get the category name and the companies that are related to the category. i don't want the query to repeat category names in cases where many companies belong to a category. i need one category name and list of companies that belongs to it only

Comment: How are you displaying this data on your website? Really you would want to make a table in java script with the categories as column headers and companies in rows below them. You would then loop through the results and add the appropriate companies to categories.